# skactions in spritekit and repositioning the sprite

Tags: sprite-kit

hi guys I have a game where there's a stone falling off the sky. now I set its skphysics gravity to yes so it would fall but the problem is I don't know how to reset its position to the top of the screen so it would repeat its falling action again.

```
- (void) addStoneAtPosition {
      _StoneNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"stone2@2x"];
      _StoneNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height);

      _StoneNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_StoneNode.size];
      _StoneNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
      _StoneNode.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
      _StoneNode.physicsBody.mass = 10.0f;
      _StoneNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CNPhysicsstone1Category;
      _StoneNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CNPhysicsbulletCategory |  
                                                  CNPhysicsstone1Category;
      [_gameNode addChild:_StoneNode];
      [_StoneNode attachDebugRectWithSize:_StoneNode.size];
      _StoneNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
      for (int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
          _StoneNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height);
      }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: if stone.position.y < some value set its position to whichever point you need. Do that in the update method of the scene.

Comment: thanks for helping bud but I am so sorry I am not sure how to do what you just recommended because see, the stone's position is at the self.size.height originally but how to go back to that position after the gravity has affected this stone?

Comment: this maybe? stone.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width, self.size.height);

Comment: well i already have this: _StoneNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height); but how would recall this after the gravity has affected my stone?

Answer (score 0):

Override [didSimulatePhysics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didSimulatePhysics) in your SKScene and check if the stone is below the bottom of the scenes viewable area.

```
if (stone.position.y < 0) { ... }
```

If it is below this viewable area you have at least two choices.

1) Remove the stone from the scene by calling `[stone removeFromParent];` and recreate a new one in the same way you created your original stone.

or

2) Set the position of your stone to somewhere above the top of your view

```
stone.position = CGPointMake(stone.position.x, stone.scene.size.height + stoneHeight);
```

Comment: This is outside the scope of your question but I would like to recommend you look at using [SpriteKit-Components](https://github.com/buddingmonkey/SpriteKit-Components) it allows you to implement these methods directly inside your custom node sub classes or even keep them completely separate.  I have found it very helpful, and it keeps your scene class a much more tidy place.